# Friend function is unable to construct a unique pointer of the class

Tags: c++, c++11, friend, unique-ptr

I have a certain design strategy where the constructor of my class is private and can only be constructed by friends of the class. Inside the friend function, I am trying to create a unique_pointer of my class using `std::make_unique`but it doesn't compile. My VC12 compiler complains

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\memory(1639): error C2248: 'Spam::Spam' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Spam'

The relevant code which fails during compilation is as follows

```
#include <memory>
class Spam {
public:
    friend void Foo();

private:
    Spam(int mem) :mem(mem) {}
    int mem;
};
void Foo() {
    std::unique_ptr<Spam> spam = std::make_unique<Spam>(10);
}
```

Why am I not able to compile?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your case the function `make_unique` is trying to create an instance of `Spam` and that function is not a friend. Calling a non-friend function from inside a friend function does not imbue the non-friend function with friend status.

To solve this you can write in `Foo`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Spam> spam(new Spam(10));
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. Can you please add more details to the answer?

Comment: There's no guarantee that `make_unique` won't delegate to an internal helper, in which case your `friend` will not work (not to mention that the signature is also wrong because `make_unique` takes its arguments by forwarding reference).

Comment: In general, this approach is susceptible to the problems `make_unique` is supposed to solve (namely the potential for memory leak)

Answer (score 20):

Here is another approach I've seen used, apparently known as the *passkey idiom* : have the public constructor require a private access token.

```
class Spam {
    struct Token {};
    friend void Foo();
public:
    Spam(Token, int mem) : mem(mem) {}

private:
    int mem;
};

void Foo() {
    std::unique_ptr<Spam> spam = std::make_unique<Spam>(Spam::Token{}, 10);
}

void Bar() {
    // error: 'Spam::Token Spam::token' is private
    // std::unique_ptr<Spam> spam = std::make_unique<Spam>(Spam::Token{}, 10);
}
```

Comment: The code compiles, but does not link with an error "undefined reference to `Spam::token'"

Comment: @MathieuDutourSikiric wow, and it took three years before someone noticed as well... Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you even need the `Spam::Token` preceding the `{}`

Comment: @Caleth I wouldn't if it wasn't for `std::make_unique` which needs to forward it, and thus know its type :)

Comment: Thanks for correction, but I wonder how it addresses the initial issue. The initial problem is that the constructor is private and make_unique is not friended with Spam. In your code the constructor is public. That certainly addresses the issue, but how are the Spam::Token helpful in this?

Comment: @MathieuDutourSikiric the constructor is visible to all, but only callable by those who can provide a `Token`, that is either the friends or whoever the friends give a token to.

Comment: Thanks! Objectively, it looks kind of crazy construction, but why not.

Comment: This is called the "passkey idiom".

Comment: @Quentin: passkey idiom is unfortunately more complicated, private key is [not enough](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/387cf00e8c517dae), key might be public with private  constructor (with friend access): [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6c9caebb34fa870)

Comment: More on what Jarod42 is pointing out: https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/

Answer (score 6):

```
Why am I not able to compile?
```

You are unable to compile because `make_unique` is not a friend of `Spam`.

An alternative solution to making `make_unique` a friend is to move the creation of the unique_ptr into `Spam`.

```
class Spam {
   ...
private:
   Spam(int) {}

   static unique_ptr<Spam> create( int i ) 
   { return std::unique_ptr<Spam>( new Spam(i) ); }
};
```

and then have `Foo` call that instead.

```
void Foo() {
    std::unique_ptr<Spam> spam = Spam::create(10);
    ...
}
```

Comment: How is this any better than just using `new` directly in `Foo`?

Comment: The use of such a construction is to force the user of the API into RAII. That way it is more difficult to create a memory leak. Calling Foo will delete spam and spam will be deleted if an exception is thrown later on inside Foo.

Comment: But you are not forcing RAII: `Foo` can still call `new` if it wants since it is a friend. And it may decide to use `unique_ptr` in any case. The point is that `make_unique` is preferable to new. If you are going to drop it, then I don't see the benefit of the added complexity in this approach.

Comment: I agree with @ricab: Isn't the entire point that `Span::create` should call `std::make_unique<Spam>(i)`?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `Foo()` is a `friend`, but it isn't the function that's creating the `Spam` - `make_unique` is internally calling `new Spam` itself. The simple fix is to just have `Foo()` actually construct the `Spam` directly:

```
void Foo() {
    std::unique_ptr<Spam> spam(new Spam(10));
}
```